# before img add and close anchor tag using in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have the following code

```
<div id="slider">    
    <img src="images/p1.jpg" />
    <img src="images/p2.jpg" />
    <img src="images/p3.jpg" /> 
</div>
```

I want to add `<a>` before and after the image tag with jQuery. This would be the result:

```
<div id="slider">    
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/p1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/p2.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/p3.jpg" /></a>    
</div>
```

---

**Edit: Details from comments**

So far, I have tried like this:

```
<span class="phone"><img src="malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg"></span>
<span class="phone"><img src="malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg"></span>
<span class="phone"><img src="malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg"></span>
<span class="phone"><img src="malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg"></span>
```

i have add like

```
$('.phone').each(function() { 
    $(this).wrapInner('<a href="test.php" />'); 
});
```

---

**Additional information from comments**

I want to use a different url for each image, like:

```
<div id="slider">
  <a href="google.com"><img src="images/p1.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="yahoo.com"><img src="images/p2.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="facebook.com"><img src="images/p3.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all the details you have provided in comments. (The edit by @freedomn-m seems helpful but I'm not sure it includes all the scattered comments -- please review.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the JQuery `wrap()` function like so:

```
var arr = ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.yahoo.com/', 'https://www.bing.com/'];

$("#slider img").each(function(index, value){
    $(this).wrap("<a href='"+arr[index]+"'></a>");
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jzxuqeLo/)

Comment: thanks bro but i want to different url apply every iamge .like..
<div id="slider">    
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/p1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><img src="images/p2.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/p3.jpg" /></a>    
</div>

Comment: @MahendraPrajapati maybe add this to your question?  The question looks like the same url for every link

Comment: @MahendraPrajapati Add it to ur question as freedomn-m mentioned else its misleading.  And you can store your links in an array and assign them individually as you loop through the tags

Comment: hi thanks for reply dear,
other person modify my question but actual my requirement as i want add different URL ..LIke

<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="p1.jpg"></a>

Comment: @MahendraPrajapati Ur wecome :) Can you mark as answer pls? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

> Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

Here you can store different url in custom attributes which can later be used to wrap element.

```js
$('#slider img').wrap(function() {
  return $('<a />', {
    "href": $(this).data('url'),
    "class" : "myClass"
  });
})
```

```css
.myClass {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <img src="images/p1.jpg" data-url='facebook.com' />
  <img src="images/p2.jpg" data-url='google.com' />
  <img src="images/p3.jpg" data-url='example.com' />
</div>
```